# percentages in an array of varying input

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on an assignment for my computer course and our task is to write a method that analyzes the array "numbers" and return an array representing for each digit, the proportion of times it occurred as a leading digit...

ie
{ 100, 200.1, 9.3, 10}
then 1 occurs as a leading digit 50 % of the time, 2 occurs 25% of the time, and 9 occurs 25 % of the time, so your produced array should contain:
{0, .5, .25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, .25}

I'm having issues getting started, it's suggested that we write a helper method called, for example, countLeadingDigits which returns an array of counts for each digit and only then calculate the percentages. I don't know how to go about writing the method that takes an unknown number of input doubles from the user then store the number of times each digit appears as a leading digit.. I've already written the part of the code that calculates the leading digit. Any hints pleasee?

Comment: Your output array is not clear, how do you get that?

Comment: for better help, post your code.

Comment: Please post the code you have already written.

Comment: we're not aloud to use the program ArrayList, we haven't covered that in class yet..

Comment: infinite input as in the number of numbers inputed is decided by the user and not know when writing the program

Comment: Is your input an array of numbers (as your first paragraph would indicate), or entered by the user (as your last paragraph would indicate)?

Comment: So your question appears to be "How to I take input from a user when I can't use a dynamic `List` to store it?". Create an array of a reasonable size. If it gets filled, create a new one 2x that size and copy contents of the first into it. Repeat as necessary. Option B is asking the user how many numbers they would like to input and then only taking that many.

Comment: Those who doesn't understand how the output array is populated with the said input array should try to think logically, I find the description clear enough. (Even though the rest of the post is kinda messy)

Comment: How will the input be provided? from command line during start of the program - as arguments array? Or rather as input read by `Scanner` a'la `cin` @ C++0?

Answer (score 1):

A solution with short and intense code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double[] inputs = { 100, 200.1, 9.3, 10 , -100 }; // your inputs
    double sum = inputs.length;

    int[] leadingDigitCounters = new int[10]; // counters for 0...9

    // Here is how you increment respective leading-digit counters
    for (double d : inputs) 
    {
        int j = Integer.parseInt((d + "").replace("-", "").charAt(0) + "");
        leadingDigitCounters[j]++;
    }   

    // Printing out respective percentages
    for (int i : leadingDigitCounters)
        System.out.print((i / sum) + " ");
}
```

**Output:**

> 0.0 0.6 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.2

Comment: and what happens for input == -5?

Comment: Yeah, your approach would be mine as well, but I just realized, that I was working on something where number_as_string could start from minus and that was one of biggest issues :)

Comment: @dantuch see my edit. now it handles negative numbers as well =)

Comment: This makes sense - thank you very much! The only other thing is that how would you make it so that you can choose the inputs when you run the program.. So they're not actually known when you're writing the method, but entered by the user by use of a keyboard scanner or something.. Thank you for your help